# Print out 2 digit numbers using only one integer and putchar

Tags: c, stdio, putchar

I have to print out 2 digit numbers **(*`00, 01, 02, 03,... ,10, 11,..99`*)** i.e. from `00 to 99` using only **one integer** and function `putchar()`.

In *ASCII* table, these are signs from `0x30` (0) to `0x39`(9).

Also i may only use `stdio.h` library.

Output example:

```
00  
01  
02  
03  
...(all the way to 99)
99
```

Which operation would you suggest to make this possible?
I already made working solution but I had to use two integers (one from first part of 2 digit number, and other for second). But this is not allowed.

Comment: What a ridiculous requirement...

Comment: Reading [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), and [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good start. And learning how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I also recommend [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: im not fan of it either but it is required to do it this way

Comment: It might as well be impossible with only `putchar`.

Comment: Check if that integer is < 10 and then append a zero in front of it? Or is that also not allowed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a homework completion service. Your instructor gave you the assignment, not us, and you're going to need to do your own work. If you can't get started, ask your teacher for help; they're being paid to teach you. Good luck.

Comment: As for your assignment, it's a simple `for` loop, with some basic arithmetic (modulo, division, addition).

Comment: Hint: call `putchar` twice, once for for each digit, using % 10 and / 10 to get each one.

Comment: how i see it, the only reasonable approach would be to use `putchar() two times`: one for first part of digit and second time for second part.. For example: `int x = 0x30`  `putchar(x)` `putchar(x+1)` will produce `01`...(increment x each time 0x39)...

Comment: Hint: Try doing e.g. `5 + '0'`. What is the result? If you print that as a character (using e.g. `putchar`), what do you print?

Comment: @Totenkoph93 You can do `int main(void) { int i=0; while(i<100) { putchar('0'+i/10); putchar('0'+i%10); putchar('\n'); i++; } return 0; }`. See it [working here](https://ideone.com/R0odZr).

Comment: thank you very much for proposed solutions and sorry for posting a trivial question as this one, i will do my best to improve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100 ; i++){

    putchar((i/10)+'0');
    putchar((i%10)+'0');
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: thank you i guess that was all i needed

Comment: Try to avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) as much as possible. The divisions and modulos with `10` are pretty clear (with a little comments) but `+ 0x30`? If you do `+ '0'` it's usually much clearer (and more portable).

Comment: @Some programmer dude yes, absolutely agree with you (edited it)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. And you're defining only one integer.

```
void foo()
{
    int a = 0;
    while(a <= 99)
    {
        if(a < 10)
        {
            putchar((char)i/10 + '0');
            putchar((char)a%10 + '0');
            putchar('\n');
        }
        a++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Infinite loop for `a`?

Comment: `a` < 99? Shouldn't it be `a`<100? And I don't think that `if-else` is needed.

Comment: The `if-else` is not needed at all.

Comment: doesn't even compile - missing ; after \n and and not printing 99